# Dynamically use another database's table if the current database does not have the respective table

Tags: sql, database

I have two different database exist in the same server. One is the mainDB which are actively using, and another is an archiveDB that stores previous data.

But the problem for archiveDB is, only some tables from mainDB will be stored inside archiveDB.

And now, i had to query records that were inside archiveDB. For my query, i am getting error "Invalid object name xx.xx.tableName". The error is due to not having the table name in archiveDB. I am not able to manually convert those table that does not exist in archiveDB to mainDB because i do not know which table does not exist in archiveDB.

Therefore, I need to make my query dynamic so that table that does not exist in archiveDB will automatically use mainDB to retrieve the data.

Is there a way to make my query dynamic as mentioned above? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It depends on database you use and from where you execute query (from client or from stored proc) . In most cases you cant execute query against two databases. You should use db specific tricks for this. For example https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm or proccess data from two queries

Comment: Also you may need construct text of your query dynamically but in mosy cases what tables should queried is known in advance so you dont need to query a table from the "wrong" database